# To much records in multiple MySQL relation (relation with adding relation) - GROUP BY with JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, relation

i have 3 tables:

```
# table1 #
## id ##
   1

# table2 #
## id    table1 ##
   1       1
   2       1
   3       1

# table3 #
## id    table2 ##
   1       1
   2       1
   3       2
   4       2
   5       3
   6       3
```

And query, who join 3 tables in single query

```
Select COUNT(t2.id)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.table1 = t1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.table2 = t2.id
WHERE t1.id = 1
GROUP BY t1.id
```

COUNT(t2.id) should return 3, but i get 6 - I think that is because every record from table2 have 2 records in table3.

Maybe I should change this line?

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.t2 = t2.id
```

Maybe group this or something? But how do this?

======================================
edit

add to table2 column "price"

```
# table2 #
## id    table1    price ##
   1       1        10
   2       1        20
   3       1        10

Select SUM(t2.price)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.table1 = t1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.table2 = t2.id
WHERE t1.id = 1
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Now, when I want to sum the price I get 80, but I should get 40 - distinct is not good solution, because price is not unique.

Comment: You outer join table 3, but select no columns from that table. This makes no sense.

Comment: I work with more extensive query - this is simple description of my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
Select COUNT(t2.id)
```

to

```
Select COUNT(distinct t2.id)
```

and remove the `group by` since you select only one group anyway with `WHERE t1.id = 1`

Comment: This is not exactly that what I need. Suppose - in table2 I have another column "price" and in my query I trying to get this: SUM(t2.price) - then I get double sum - reason as above. Distinct is not good idea, becouse this column don't have unique value. How I can resolve this?

Comment: Then you either need to adjust your join to have only one record and not 2 for every joined table or you put the join of `t2` in a subquery and group the data.

Answer (score 0):

**You said:**
If this is not exactly that what I need. Suppose - in table2 I have another column "price" and in my query I trying to get this: SUM(t2.price) - then I get double sum - reason as above. Distinct is not good idea, becouse this column don't have unique value. How I can resolve this?

Remove the join to table3:

```
Select COUNT(t2.id)
FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.table1 = t1.id
WHERE t1.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are joining against t3 you are expanding the rows to 6.

```
Select sum(t2.price)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.table1 = t1.id
WHERE t1.id = 1;
```

Please check SQL Fiddle 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2236fb/11

Comment: "When you are joining against t3 you are expanding the rows to 6." - this is the point...
In my oryginal query i get from table3 another sum - I need this table. Can I resolve this without using subquery?

Comment: Ya a subquery would be only real solution. Just make sure you index well and it would be fast.